# Where does Jimmy get cash to the 1.6 Million dollar cash pile whole again?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

In ***Better Call Saul***, season 1.

Jimmy hires Mike to retrieve the stolen cash from the Kettleman's property, then Jimmy puts some cash back in before returning it to the DA office.

- The Kettleman pay Jimmy a retainer of 30k in cash when Jimmy find them in the wilderness, hiding in a camp.
- Jimmy spends a portion of this 30k on a nice suit, a billboard and perhaps some other things.
- When Jimmy takes out 10k cash from his shoe box to give it to Mike, we can see there is almost no money left from the 30k cash.

My question is:

- How does Jimmy manage to pay back the 30k cash to the 1.6 Million dollar pile after he has spent almost 2/3 of it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one, the 10k bundle Saul gives to Mike is the one he uses in the scheme to detect where the money is hidden, so that one is back in the bag.

The remaining 20k I assume is money Saul has earned in the past weeks and/or previous savings.

Comment: I'd assume Mike's bait 10k plus Saul's 10 from the ceiling would be enough to put paid to their scheme to counter-accuse him on the full 30k bribe. Assuming the Kettlemans haven't spent any, of which there's no real indication, then the pot is only shy by 10k now.